# How can I search online for sounds according to their waveform (or spectral) shape?

Tags: sound-effects, sound-libraries, search

I did come across this site, but the results here are finite and few:

[wave shape generator](http://www.findsounds.com/)

Is there are better way to search for this?  Or anyway, a better search engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not free, but our individual download site has a waveform viewer: http://download.prosoundeffects.com   There's also a "Sonic Search" function that looks for tracks sonically similar to a particular YouTube or Soundcloud track. It was originally designed for music, but it might give you some interesting results for sound effects too. Click the up arrow in the search bar to access that function.

Get one free download here: http://www.prosoundeffects.com/online-library-trial-1-download.html

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to **Freesound**:

http://www.freesound.org/search/

There are some sounds with really good quality, and they are all [creative common](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/) licensed (free to use).